# Get local port numbers in windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, powershell-5.0

I am trying to get all **local ports** that are in **listening** state. Using

```
netstat -a -n
```

I get the following output:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING //for example, demo data is given
```

But I only wan't to get the port numbers.

```
1111 //for ex, this is in listening state.
```

In Windows 10, I can use

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | group localport -NoElement
```

Which works but this command isn't available on Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether there is a Windows 7 cmdlet available but you could parse the netstat result:

```
$objects = netstat -a -n | 
    select -Skip 4 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_ -split ' ' | Where-Object {$_ -ne ''}   
        if ($line.Count -eq 4)
        {
           New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            'Protocol'=$line[0]
            'LocalAddress'=$line[1]
            'ForeignAddress'=$line[2]
            'State'=$line[3]}
        }
    }
```

Then you can retrieve the ports using something like this:

```
$objects | Where State -eq LISTENING | Select LocalAddress | Foreach { 
    $_ -replace '.*:(\d+).*', '$1' 
}
```